# Generate full combination with out cyclic rotations

Tags: python, numpy, combinatorics

I have a problem, I am engaged in scientific research and there is a need to generate a binary sequence of a certain length.
I use the numpy library to generate combinations. I found the following code on the Internet:

```
np.array(np.meshgrid(*[[1, 0] for x in range(size)])).T.reshape(-1, size)
```

It works, and it works fast, but it creates all combinations of a certain length.
if size = 3

```
    [1 1 1]
    [1 0 1]
    [0 1 1]
    [0 0 1]
    [1 1 0]
    [1 0 0]
    [0 1 0]
    [0 0 0]
```

I need to generate combinations in such a way as to remove all cyclidal copies, i.e.:

```
    [1 1 1]
    [1 0 1]
    [0 1 1] because [1 0 1] and [1 1 0]  are cyclic displacements
    [0 0 1]
    [1 1 0]
    [1 0 0]
    [0 1 0]
    [0 0 0]
```

It is necessary to write a function that will generate all allowed combinations of any length. from 3 to 1000 elements. Another question is how to save it))

I created some really terrible code, which I'm ashamed of, but it seems to work.

```
def gen_matrix(size):
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*[[1, 0] for x in range(0, size)])).T.reshape(-1, size)


def build_matrix(size_row):
    a = gen_matrix(size_row)
    kill = True
    while kill:
        kill = False
        for i in a:
            if kill:
                break
            for j in range(1, size_row):
                b = np.roll(i, j)
                if np.array_equal(i, b):
                    continue
                k = np.where((a == b).all(axis=1))
                if np.size(k) > 0:
                    a = np.delete(a, k[0], 0)
                    kill = True
    return a

result:
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 1 1 1]
[0 1 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 1 1]
[0 0 1 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0]
```

It will be difficult to describe in 2 lines. There are such combinatorial sequences as perfect golden rings (PGR), they are somewhat similar to Golomb lines, but have a cyclic structure. There is a general rule by which you can check the truth of the sequence, the sums of adjacent numbers exhaust the entire set from 1 to Sn, where Sn is determined by the formula or is simply the sum of all numbers. For example, PGR (1,2,4) => 1, 2, 1+2=3, 4,4+1=5, 2+4=6,1+2+4=7. You can add numbers to the circle. There are several PGRs in which the number of sum options can be greater than 1, i.e. PGR (1,1,2,3), since "1" = 2, it is possible to form contiguous sums from 1 to 7 in two ways. . . Generated in various ways, one of which is the generation of cyclic codes, for example, PGR (1,2,4) can be written as 1101000. Sequence digits are the number of "0" between "1". I have a task, I managed to find sequences up to Sn =35. Now I need to find other combinations. I used to do full enumeration, meaning the number of combinations is 2^N, where N is the number of bits, but the higher the order, the more difficult it is. So now I have set myself a goal. 1. Optimization of the input array of potential codes. 2. compute it on the GPU.
actually i need to generate all the combinations of the binary sequence but remove all the cyclic copies.
2^12 = 4096 total options
if cyclic copies are removed from them, the number of variations will be 352.

Comment: can you show what you'd want for ```size=4``` or something larger, ```size=3``` isn't particularly useful

Comment: no, I mean change your question, because for ```size=3``` my answer is correct, though I suspect it isn't what you're looking for for higher sizes as for ```size=3``` the ordering doesn't matter for the cyclic combinations

Comment: for instance, with ```size=4``` are these considered the same? ```[0, 1, 0, 1]``` and ```[0, 1, 1, 0]```

Comment: You want to do this for length 1000? How much time and memory do you have? Are you immortal?

Comment: @Nin17, no [0, 1, 0, 1] and [0, 1, 1, 0] they are different

Comment: @KellyBundy, I wanted to build a drarry and send it in batches for processing in the gpu

Comment: I don't know what a drarry is, but all the GPUs in the world combined can't do that in your lifetime.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I updated the question and described the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [itertools.combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement((0, 1), r=3))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: almost, but not quite what is needed.